# Run exe file from other nodes

Tags: windows, mpi, cluster-computing, command-prompt, mpiexec

I have a cluster nodes containing 2 PCs.How can i run specific exe file from one node in other node(for example from node 0). I must run executable file simultaneously for parallel run from command prompt in the first node. But when i run `mpiexec -n 2 -ppn 1 -f host.txt c.exe` in the first node [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/ec/5e/error.jpg) error appear. [Host file](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a0/7a/host.txt)  just containing IP addresses of nodes and all exe file are in a same location in all nodes. How can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: can you try to use an absolute path (e.g. /home/xyz/c.exe) instead of just the executable name (e.g. c.exe) ?

Comment: When i use full path this error appeared: Credentials for Aeroman rejected connecting to Aeroman. (Aeroman is my host name). i use this command:  mpiexec -n 1 -ppn 1 <full direction to the folder containing the exe file>/c.exe